# Opencart Order List by status

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, foreach, opencart

I'm currently using opencart, in the admin panel there is an orders section.

Within the code there is a loop that displays each order.
here is the loop

```
<?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align: center;"><?php if ($order['selected']) { ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>" checked="checked" />
                <?php } else { ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $order['order_id']; ?>" />
                <?php } ?></td>
              <td class="right"><?php echo $order['order_id']; ?></td>
              <td class="left"><?php echo $order['customer']; ?></td>
              <td class="left"><?php echo $order['status']; ?></td>
              <td class="right"><?php echo $order['total']; ?></td>
              <td class="left"><?php echo $order['date_added']; ?></td>
              <td class="left"><?php echo $order['date_modified']; ?></td>
              <td class="right"><?php foreach ($order['action'] as $action) { ?>
                [ <a href="<?php echo $action['href']; ?>"><?php echo $action['text']; ?></a> ]
                <?php } ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

There is also a filter above this to sort orders.

```
<tr class="filter">
              <td></td>
              <td align="right"><input type="text" name="filter_order_id" value="<?php echo $filter_order_id; ?>" size="4" style="text-align: right;" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="filter_customer" value="<?php echo $filter_customer; ?>" /></td>
              <td><select name="filter_order_status_id">
                  <option value="*"></option>
                  <?php if ($filter_order_status_id == '0') { ?>
                  <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_missing; ?></option>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <option value="0"><?php echo $text_missing; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php foreach ($order_statuses as $order_status) { ?>
                  <?php if ($order_status['order_status_id'] == $filter_order_status_id) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $order_status['order_status_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $order_status['name']; ?></option>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $order_status['order_status_id']; ?>"><?php echo $order_status['name']; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                </select></td>
              <td align="right"><input type="text" name="filter_total" value="<?php echo $filter_total; ?>" size="4" style="text-align: right;" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="filter_date_added" value="<?php echo $filter_date_added; ?>" size="12" class="date" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="filter_date_modified" value="<?php echo $filter_date_modified; ?>" size="12" class="date" /></td>
              <td align="right"><a onclick="filter();" class="button"><?php echo $button_filter; ?></a></td>
            </tr>
```

What i'm trying to do is underneath the orders, display all the orders in another table with a set status.

for example, when an order is complete (status id = 5) i want it to move from one table to another

[image]

you can see the "complete order" which has a status_id of "5" and the pending orders which have an order_status of "1".

I'm not worried about how the table looks, i can do that within a loop, but i don't know how to get the information into a loop to display orders with a set status, I've already tried

```
<?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>
  <?php if ($order_status['order_status_id'] = 5 ?>
    some data here
  <?php ?>
<?php ?>
```

and

```
<?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>
  <?php if ($order['status'] = 5 ?>
    some data here
  <?php ?>
<?php ?>
```

Am i getting things around the wrong way?

The loops isn't working, I've also tried putting the if statement before the foreach for both of the above, but its not working.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

`if( $order['status'] == 'Complete' ) {
  //code
}`

```
== is comparison operator where as = is an assignment operator
```

this code should be inside `<?php foreach ($orders as $order) { ?>`,

also note that `$order['status']` gives order status text and not a integer so make your conditions accordingly. See `order_status` db table for all order statuses

Also your parentheses are not matching